# Why was the code cracking device needed in S02E10?

Tags: plot-explanation, mission-impossible, mission-impossible-tv

In the episode "For Art's Sake" (S02E10) of the 1988 run of [*Mission: Impossible*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094511/) when Nicholas, disguised as Minister Ocha, is lead by Travers into his vault, he achieves to film Travers typing a numbered door code into the panel next to the vault door, using some kind of pin camera. But later, when Grant and Max break into Travers' vault to mess with his paintings, they use some kind of code cracking device to determine and type in the code.

[image]

But **why did they need this elaborate method of cracking the code at all?** Shouldn't they have known the code from Nicholas' camera and could have just typed it in normally? Or was it that they didn't want to touch the code panel for some reason? Was this just some kind of inconsistency or did I maybe miss anything here that makes this a little more coherent?

Comment: seems that they wanted a reason to use the [Safecracking Trope] (http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Safecracking) - maybe for a more dramatic effect?

Comment: What's the timing of first, second and third scene ?

Comment: @noob I don't know. The first two images are when Nicholas, disguised as Minister Ocha is led by Travers into the vault and the third one is when Grant and Max break into it, as the question explains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed out a thing. Tune to following time if you have that episode.

> 00:37:45 --> 00:37:48
>
> GRANT: Palm print identifier, sensor detonation. Quite a minefield.

Here Grant analyses the pictures taken by the **cuff camera**. Those are static photos (note the shutter effect) of the types of security checks, paintings and other stuff. They're used as a *point of reference*, telling them *where* the keypad is (they didn't see it last time, when they tried to follow him and the signal was blocked) and what *kind* of keypad it is.

Later they use their cracking device because they don't actually know the code. They just know what **kind** of check is applied. And even if they *did* know (since Nicholas could see it being typed), *it's probably best not to risk it* in case Travers changes passwords frequently and an alarm goes off. It ends up being the same code every time (4193), but better safe than sorry.

Note that when the device is used it processes and **correct digits blink** which is then typed by them in order to bypass it.

Watch this [episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-RkNVJ7foAE) from 35:00 to 40:00. Notice that the **cuff camera** is static and when they crack the code using device, it blinks the digits first.

Comment: No, what Grant is talking about there is the security for the actual painting *inside* the gallery, not the gallery door. The painting is indeed secured by an actual palm sensor. That's not the code field at the entrance of the gallery that the question is talking about.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I have updated my answer.

Comment: But why did they not know the code when Nicholas filmed it? So was it only photos they could take?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Yes it was a camera for **static photos**. I guess they didn't thought that cameras that small could record motion picture in future. Whom to blame it was 1988. Perhaps they did wanted to show off the code breaker.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson noob is correct: the camera shot *photographs*, not video (note how it operates). Of course, it still makes little sense because if Nicholas had a clear shot, he could obviously see the code being typed in and could've just *tell them* what it was. Seems they just ignored that fact so they could use a cool device later.

Comment: (...On the other hand, they probably couldn't afford the risk. Travers might be the kind of person who changes his passwords frequently, and if they typed in the wrong code, it could've triggered an alarm. So it might make *some* sense just to use the device, I guess.)

Comment: @Walt: A very good point.

Comment: @noob Would you mind if I added them to your answer?

Comment: @Walt: Not at all.

Comment: Congratulations, this answer is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: Woha ! Thanks !! Initially I answered just by reading script of that episode because I couldn't find it's video. Only when I got it on youtube I confirmed my speculations.